# Symfony2 form result in subrequest

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm redering my header twig from the base twig as a sub request. The following code line is in the base twig.

```
{{ render(controller('MyBundle:Global:header')) }}
```

In the header twig there is a search form. Not linked to any entity with the following definitions. This is the TopSearchType form definition.

```
        $builder
        ->add('searchKey', 'text', array('mapped' => false))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
```

In the sub controller I make the form and handle the validation result as follow.

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new TopSearchType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        dump($form['searchKey']->getData());
    }
```

The form is generated but the result is not triggered? When I run the same code directly in the base twig it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, your controller's action (Global:header) is being triggered by the `render` method, and when you submit it it's probably going to the action you're at on the page the `header` method is being rendered.

You probably should create a separate action only to handle the post of the form, then use it as the form's action.

If you want to redirect the user to the current page you could add a hidden field storing the current URL, and then redirect him after the search.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to catch the action and handling it in an separate controller? So it is not possibly to handle it in the header controller as this one is already separate? That is I believe the nicest solution.

Comment: Yes, you can handle it in the header controller, that's perfectly fine. Is this already happening? Can you check the form's action URL to see if it's pointing to the header controller's route?